# Center text for receipt printing

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, alignment

I have some code which I'm using to print a receipt from C#.

The code below prints OK but I'm struggling with aligning the text left right and center,

```
Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
Font font = new Font("Courier New", 10);
float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();
int startX = 0;
int startY = 0;
int Offset = 0;

graphics.DrawString("Welcome to MSST", new Font("Courier New", 14), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
Offset = Offset + 20;

graphics.DrawString("Recept No :" + receptno + 1, new Font("Courier New", 14), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
Offset = Offset + 20;

graphics.DrawString("Date :" + DateTime.Today, new Font("Courier New", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
Offset = Offset + 20;

graphics.DrawString("------------------------------------------", new Font("Courier New", 10), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
Offset = Offset + 20;
```

Can anyone help me out with text align?

**UPDATE:** Here is the desired output:

```
             Welcome to MSST             
Receipt No : 3
Date : 5/24/2014 10:06:22
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What do you want your final output to be? (What do you want centered,  aligned right/left?)

Comment: Id like the text "welcome to MSST centered

Comment: You should look into [string formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.stringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)!  Give the drawstring method a layout rectanlge.

Comment: If you're using a monospaced font (Courier New), you can center text by counting characters and prefixing with the appropriate number of spaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the full code of your example, using three `StringFormats` and an added line to show right aligned text.. I have also added a leading number and converted everything to `floats`.. I was using a `Panel` to draw on and set the layout `Rectangle` to the Panel's dimensions. You should use your printing target, of course..

[image]

```
int receptno = 42;
Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;

Font font10 = new Font("Courier New", 10);
Font font12 = new Font("Courier New", 12);
Font font14 = new Font("Courier New", 14);

float leading = 4;
float lineheight10 = font10.GetHeight() + leading;
float lineheight12 = font12.GetHeight() + leading;
float lineheight14 = font14.GetHeight() + leading;

float startX = 0;
float startY = leading;
float Offset = 0;

StringFormat formatLeft = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);
StringFormat formatCenter = new StringFormat(formatLeft);
StringFormat formatRight = new StringFormat(formatLeft);

formatCenter.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
formatRight.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
formatLeft.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

SizeF layoutSize = new SizeF(yourPrintAreaWidth - Offset * 2, lineheight14);
RectangleF layout = new RectangleF(new PointF(startX, startY + Offset), layoutSize);

Brush  brush = Brushes.Black;

graphics.DrawString("Welcome to MSST", font14, brush, layout, formatCenter);
Offset = Offset + lineheight14;
layout = new RectangleF(new PointF(startX, startY + Offset), layoutSize);
graphics.DrawString("Recept No :" + receptno + 1, font14, brush, layout, formatLeft);
Offset = Offset + lineheight14;
layout = new RectangleF(new PointF(startX, startY + Offset), layoutSize);
graphics.DrawString("Date :" + DateTime.Today, font12, brush, layout, formatLeft);
Offset = Offset + lineheight12;
layout = new RectangleF(new PointF(startX, startY + Offset), layoutSize);
graphics.DrawString("".PadRight(46,'_'), font10, brush, layout, formatLeft);
Offset = Offset + lineheight10;
layout = new RectangleF(new PointF(startX, startY + Offset), layoutSize);

graphics.DrawString("copyright SO", font10, brush, layout, formatRight);
Offset = Offset + lineheight10;

font10.Dispose();   font12.Dispose();  font14.Dispose();
```

Comment: Can you emplane where this line comes from please ...SizeF layoutSize = new SizeF(panel6.ClientSize.Width - Offset * 2, lineheight14); as i get an error with panel6

Comment: As I wrote in my answer I use a panel for the width of the __layout rectangle width__. You must use some other measure for your desired width, maybe `PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width`, but this is for you to decide! You always need some layout rectangle if you want to __center or right align__ text - sounds logical, yes?

Answer (score 1):

This code will work for text center

```
Center = Convert.ToSingle(e.PageBounds.Width / 2 - e.Graphics.MeasureString("Valley boulevard Auto Center", HeadingFont).Width / 2)
```