# How to assign the listview text to be on the right in print preview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, printing

I have listview in form1 and in print preview I use the below code to get the column but the text on the listview are on the right when I view them in the print preview..

They are on the right please help me how to make them on the right when the print preview display.

```
 int[] X = { 40, 100, 160, 540, 650 }; //relative to Left margin510

 int Y = 450; //relative to Top margin

 Font F = listView3.Font;

 Brush B = new SolidBrush(listView3.ForeColor);// 

 for (int I = 0; I < listView3.Items.Count; I++)
 {
      for (int J = 0; J < listView3.Items[I].SubItems.Count; J++)
      {
          e.Graphics.DrawString(listView3.Items[I].SubItems[J].Text, F, B, X[J], Y );//

      }
      Y += F.Height;
  }
```

Comment: Please re-read and correct your question. It looks as if you have at least once mixed up left and right! Also Make sure to understand the difference between placment of text and its alignment!! Maybe the question title should be: "How to left-align ListView Text when printing?"

Comment: Also: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425393/center-text-for-receipt-printing/30435762?s=4|0.0000#30435762) for an example that uses all sorts of placement and alignment..