# Centering text to middle in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I have two strings and one image, that I would like to print out physically. The problem I have, is that whenever the text gets too long, it looks of center. I have the following code, to "center" the text, so that it is just above the image, and position the second text to be in the lower left part of the image.

```
graphic.DrawString(textBox1.Text, font, Brushes.Black, pageWidth*0.5f,pageHeight*0.1f);
graphic.DrawString(textBox2.Text, fontSmall, Brushes.Black, pageWidth*0.27f, pageHeight*0.52f);
```

How do I make the text be always centered, for example, if you use middle alignment in word, it spaces out text, so that it goes both sides, not only one?

```
float pageWidth = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width;
float pageHeight = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height;
Font font = new Font("Arial", 90, FontStyle.Bold);
Font fontSmall = new Font("Arial", 30, FontStyle.Bold);

StringFormat str = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);
str.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;

SizeF textSize = new SizeF(pageHeight, font.Height);//pageWidth*0.2f);
SizeF barcodeSize = new SizeF(pageHeight * 0.9f, pageWidth * 0.45f);

RectangleF textBig = new RectangleF(new PointF(0f,pageWidth*0.1f), textSize);
RectangleF barcodeImageRec = new RectangleF(new PointF((pageHeight-pageHeight*0.9f)/2, textBig.Bottom), barcodeSize);
RectangleF textSmall = new RectangleF(new PointF(barcodeImageRec.Left+50, barcodeImageRec.Bottom), textSize);        

graphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;           

b.EncodedImage?.Dispose();

graphic.DrawString(textBox1.Text.ToUpper(), font, Brushes.Black, textBig, str);
b.Encode(TYPE.CODE128A, textBox2.Text.ToUpper(), Color.Black, Color.Transparent);
graphic.DrawImage(b.EncodedImage, barcodeImageRec);
str.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
graphic.DrawString(textBox2.Text.ToUpper(), fontSmall, Brushes.Black, textSmall);

font.Dispose();
fontSmall.Dispose();
```

Above you can see the edited code that I used in my printing process, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You can center text by printing it into a rectangle with a centered string format. Note that it will center, not block-align the text!

Comment: Is there an object in C#, or WinForms, that will allow me to do what I want? Since I can then make all the text/image in that object/rectangle, and use some property of it, to make the text centered (I don't know what block-align is, but I assume it is the same as words middle alignment).

Comment: Block-alignment is what you see in books, centered text is what you see in titles, some lyrics etc.. - You need to understand the difference so you know what to ask or look for! - As I wrote, centering text is simple: Just decide on the bounds and use a centered StringFormat in the DrawString! [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425393/center-text-for-receipt-printing/30435762?s=8|0.0452#30435762)

Comment: Okay, so if I understood you correctly, centering is what I want, so that when the text is `some text`, the starting point is where the space is, not where the `s` is. The first string servers as a title to the image, while the second (bottom left corner), serves as a description. Do I need to put all 3 elements (title string, image, description string) in one panel or rectangle to achieve what I want?

Comment: Yes, although I wouldn't call it 'elements' since all you do it paint some pixels. But yes, pprobably you need several DrawString calls.

Comment: Would you be so kind to show me some code, other than your link, to achieve what I want to do? The problem I have is, that the image is not always the same width/height, depending on what is being printed, so I need to either scale the image to the panel or make the panel the same size as the image.

Comment: I'll be afk for a few hours. Do you want to draw onto a Panel or into the Bitmap or to a printer??? Since you want to print to a printer all elements are basically independent and you need to scale and position them how you want. Btw: Don't forget to set/control the dpi of the image befor doing a DrawImage as it will be used in the call!!!

Comment: I mean, I want to use a rectangleF, and draw everything in the rectangle, so that I can position everything correctly, and then print all of that to a printer. I know the elements are independent, but I would like to position both the strings to be dependent on the image size/width.

Comment: Well that sounds ok. Note that the Stringformat will accept vertical and horizontal alignment indepentendtly, so it offers nine combintions/positions in your rectangle. But for the final relationship of that rectangle and the image you wll need to expand the answer! As usual a sketch will help both us and probably yourself..

Comment: Okay, I have edited with the code I am currently using. Is there anyway I can make it better? Thank you

Comment: I don't know. In general I prefer to pu tall disposable resource in a `using` clause (your fonts, maybe image). I you don't need Stringformats for the 2nd & 3rd DrawString they will be left-alignend. How does it look? Is it what you wanted?

Comment: No, there will only be two DrawStrings. First is for title, second is for description. It is sort of what I wanted, the image sometimes rescales to the point where the description doesn't really fit, but that is something out of my control (since the image is in a rectangle, the whole area is not always used). The rest is pretty much how I wanted it.

Comment: My fault, two DrawStrings. Did you take control of the bitmap's dpi? Do!

Comment: What do you mean? It should not be a problem, as I draw directly to the paper, and the image is not drawn from a file.

Comment: Well if it work it works. But you should be aware of the dpi property. You can test what happens when you change it, say: `b.SetResolution(300, 300)` or `b.SetResolution(50, 50)`. The same image will print 6x smaller or greater..

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now, so I'm not sure the class has a property like that. The `b` is actually a barcode generator class library.

Comment: ah, ok I was talking about Bitmap, which is probably what yo get from b.EncodedImage. Of course the barcode generator should allow you to set the dpi as well as the pixel size..